# Toyota Corolla revving on its own

Tags: toyota, corolla, accelerator

My 2008 corolla started revving on its own after I took my foot off the accelerator and felt like it was going to take off on its own. When I pulled over and tried to turn the car off it revved even more in neutral and park before I turned the engine off. Not sure what is wrong with it. Has anyone else had this problem and knows what is the cause?

Comment: I doubt it's anything to do with the automatic transmission. I don't know enough about it to answer, but I would suspect Throttle Position sensor

Comment: Common issue is floor mats hitting the pedal.

Comment: I'm not sure if your Corolla fell under the Toyota recall for sudden acceleration. You may want to check with Toyota and see if the mods were done to your car or if they would be required at all.

Comment: Thanks for these. It’s definitley not the mats. I will contact Toyota to find out about any recalls.

Comment: YES! Dave Smith, this has happened to me twice while my foot was on the brake! It is definitely a problem or defect! Did you bring the problem to Toyota to rectify it? Pamela Alexander